# this.<servicename> not available inside error function in angular2

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, scoping, subscribe

I have a strange error in angular2. while the following code works fine

```
loginResult.subscribe(
      (data) =>
        this.response = data,
      (err) =>

        this._ajaxService.handleError(err, 'A string to summarize the activity')
    );
```

The following code says cannot read property handleError of undefined. This happens only in case of a failed request.

```
    loginResult.subscribe(
   function (response) {

        this.response = response;
        console.log(this.response);

      },
      function (error) {

        this._ajaxService.handleError(error, 'A string to summarize the activity')

      }
    );
```

Comment: never use `function() {}` if you don't really need them, use an arrow-function instead `() => {}`. Arrow- functions keep the `this` context, the function can change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind `"this"` to both success and failure functions.

```
loginResult.subscribe(
    function (response) {
        this.response = response;
        console.log(this.response);
    }.bind(this), // <== "this" binding here
    function (error) {
        this._ajaxService.handleError(error, 'A string to summarize the activity')
    }.bind(this)
);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I found one more solution tough. using let that=this

Answer (score 2):

Use `() => {}` (an arrow function) as a callback in order for `this` to refer to the component, as the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) does not create its own `this` context:

```
  loginResult.subscribe(
      (response) => {
          this.response = response;
          console.log(this.response);
      }, 
      (error) => {
          this._ajaxService.handleError(error, 'A string to summarize the activity')
      }
  );
```

Still, if you want to use `function(){}`, you can [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) component's `this` context to the function as following:

```
  function(response){
      // now 'this' refers to the component class
  }.bind(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let that = this;
    loginResult.subscribe(
      function (res) {

        that.response = res;
        console.log(this.response);

      },
      function (error) {

        that._ajaxService.handleError(error, 'A string to summarize the activity')

      }

    );
```